# Monero Fork Seed Nodes

Tags: monero-forks, nodes, ports

There is no Monero Forking guide so started by using the original CryptoNote documentation (https://cryptonotestarter.org/inner.html). This refers to the following reference for registering Seed Nodes but it is out of date:

*src/CryptoNoteConfig.h*

```
 Add IP addresses of your seed nodes. 
    Example: 
    const std::initializer_list<const char*> SEED_NODES = {
      "111.11.11.11:17236",
      "222.22.22.22:17236",
    };
```

I am trying to find out where in the Monero codebase I register the IP Addresses of Seed Nodes. Searching within the Monero Source files, I have found the following:

*src/p2p/net_node.h line 226*

```
std::set<std::string> get_seed_nodes(cryptonote::network_type nettype) const;
```

*src/p2p/net_node.inl line 367:*

```
template<class t_payload_net_handler>
  std::set<std::string> node_server<t_payload_net_handler>::get_seed_nodes(cryptonote::network_type nettype) const
  {
    std::set<std::string> full_addrs;
    if (nettype == cryptonote::TESTNET)
    {
      full_addrs.insert("212.83.175.67:28080");
      full_addrs.insert("5.9.100.248:28080");
      full_addrs.insert("163.172.182.165:28080");
      full_addrs.insert("195.154.123.123:28080");
      full_addrs.insert("212.83.172.165:28080");
    }
    else if (nettype == cryptonote::STAGENET)
    {
      full_addrs.insert("162.210.173.150:38080");
      full_addrs.insert("162.210.173.151:38080");
    }
    else
    {
      full_addrs.insert("107.152.130.98:18080");
      full_addrs.insert("212.83.175.67:18080");
      full_addrs.insert("5.9.100.248:18080");
      full_addrs.insert("163.172.182.165:18080");
      full_addrs.insert("161.67.132.39:18080");
      full_addrs.insert("198.74.231.92:18080");
      full_addrs.insert("195.154.123.123:18080");
      full_addrs.insert("212.83.172.165:18080");
    }
    return full_addrs;
  }
```

My Questions:

1. Is this the right location for setting Seed Nodes?
2. Assuming it is the right location for setting Seed Nodes, how do I set the *nettype * variable which the above switch statement relies upon? What is best practice for using *nettype*
3. The port numbers are different. Why? For simplicity, can i just stick with the standard 18080 ?

Comment: Did you find a more up to date Forking guide? Because I'm also playing with Monero and it is hard form me to find everything in the changed code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. It is set for you based on flags passed in when launching the daemon. Without the `--testnet` or `--stagenet` flags, it defaults to mainnet.
3. Unique port numbers are used to prevent clashing with other services. A fork using the default monero ports would be very bad practice.

Comment: thanks for this. By the way, have you come across an up-to-date forking guide?

Comment: No. Why would Monero developers write a "guide" on how to fork Monero?